# Parse Rss Feeds in php inside a class

Tags: php, class, rss

It is not so bad rendering RSS feeds from an index.php page I have seen a lot of examples of it.  But I am having problems doing it from a class.  This is what I have and I am sure I have many errors...  PHP is not my strong point so if you could let me know where i am going wrong i would apprecite it...

```
<?php
class RssDisplay {

protected $fromrss;
protected $allitemscollected_feed;


public function __construct($urllink, $total_items){

    $this->fromrss = $urllink;
    $this->allitemscollected_feed = $total_items;

}

public function getItems($allitemscollected_feed){

    $feed = simplexml_load_file($this->fromrss, $this->allitemscollected_feed);

    return $feed;

    $collected_items[] =$feed;

    $this->set('collected_items', $collected_items);

}

foreach('allitemscollected' as $feed){
    $items->title;
    $items->pubDate;
    $items->description;


}


 }
```

from my index this is what I am doing:

```
 $feed = new RssDisplay('http://feeds.feedburner.com/insidethehall?format=xml');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters i would advice you to take a look at [Foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and  [PHP OPP Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) because

- Your `foreach` is not in any method
- `foreach('allitemscollected' as $feed){` is not valid because `foreach` first argument needs to be [array_expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- You class is wrong
- You did not print or echo anything
- `return $feed;` was called early which would make other codes invisible
- `$this->set(` method those not exists yet it was called `$this->set('collected_items', $collected_items);`
- `simplexml_load_file` second argument needs to be a valid class name that extends `SimpleXMLElement` yet an integer is passed

Your Simple Class you look like this

```
class RssDisplay {
    protected $maxItems;
    private $xml;

    public function __construct($url, $maxItems = 0) {
        $this->xml = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLIterator");
        $this->maxItems = $maxItems;
    }

    public function getItems() {
        return $this->xml->channel->item;
    }

    public function simpleDisplay() {
        $it = ($this->maxItems == 0) ? $this->xml->channel->item : new LimitIterator($this->xml->channel->item, 0, $this->maxItems);
        foreach ( $this->xml->channel->item as $feed ) {
            printf("<div><h2><a href='%s'>%s</a></h2><i>%s</i><p>%s</p></div><br />", $feed->link, $feed->title, $feed->pubDate, $feed->description);
        }
    }
}


$rss = new RssDisplay("http://feeds.feedburner.com/insidethehall?format=xml");
$rss->simpleDisplay();
```

Output

### Grantland previews the Hoosiers

*Fri, 02 Nov 2012 19:22:21 +0000*

Grantland: College Basketball Team Previews: Indiana There’s no shortage of offensive firepower with the Hoosiers, and the great thing about Tom Crean is that he’s never afraid to use it. Indiana was well inside the top half of the country in tempo last season, and with an extra year of chemistry it’s a good bet [...]

### Notebook: Creek shines in return from injury

*Fri, 02 Nov 2012 02:57:32 +0000*

Maurice Creek got off the bench and walked toward the Assembly Hall scorer’s table with just over 11 minutes left in the first half of Thursday night’s exhibition game against Indiana Wesleyan. Creek checked in with the official scorer, then waited patiently for the moment he’s been thinking about for more than 20 months — [...]

```
  ....... So may more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your construct takes two paremeter, but you 
used it with single paremeter.